# find a cleaner nginx location using regexp

Tags: regex, nginx

I would like to create a location that matches all but

```
http://uri/proxy-wmts
```

For example:

```
http://uri/proxy/toto
http://uri/proxy?param=value
```

I came out with that:

```
location  ~ ([^/]*)/proxy(\-[^w][^m][^t][^s])*
```

But I think it's kind of ugly, I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Why not change the order of your `location`s? If `location = /proxy-wmts` comes first, it will not be matched by any other expression. [`location` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) goes into detail with location matching order. If unclear, please paste your configuration here so we can help you. I also believe this question is better suited for [sf].

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up with yesterday, bot for the sake of curiousity, I would be glad to see an answer to that question.

Comment: And thanks for pointing me to Server Fault Lukas, didn't know that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in my comment, using proper `location` order would be much easier and more performant (matching a constant string is faster than a regular expression).

```
location = /proxy-wmts {} # matches *exactly* /proxy-wmts
location /proxy {}
```

or

```
location /proxy-wmts {} # also matches /proxy-wmts....
location /proxy {}
```

would pretty much do what you want.

---

One regular expression you could apply here is a [*zero-length negative lookahead assertion*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!...)`:

```
location ~ ([^/]*)/proxy(?!-wmts)
```

Which will match for

```
/uri/proxy
/uri/proxy-abc
/uri/proxy/abc
...
```

but not for

```
/uri/proxy-wmts
/uri/proxy-wmts-abc
/uri/proxy-wmts/abc
```